# If $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$ are topological balls, is $A\cup B$ too?

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I would be happy about an answer addressing general dimensions, but I am mostly interested in $d=4$, so I will state the question for this case.

> **Question:** Given two closed sets $A,B\subset\Bbb R^4$ so that $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$ are homeomorphic to 4-balls, then is $A\cup B$ also homeomorphic to a 4-ball?

If it helps, and to avoid pathologies, let's assume that everything is PL, i.e. all these sets are PL-homeomorphic to PL-balls.

---

**Some thoughts**

Seifert-van-Kampen suggests that the union has trivial fundamental group. That is a good start.

I though about first proving that $B\setminus A\simeq D^4$ (the 4-ball) or that $\partial A\cap\partial B\simeq S^2$ (the 2-sphere), but both are not necessarily true, already in small dimensions.

[image]

Comment: In $R^2$ with the metric $max|x_i|$ balls are squares. It is easy to find two squares with intersection being square but not the sum.

Comment: This is not rigorous at all but I think if there is a ball in a ball, then one can always collapse the larger one into the smaller one. (Perhaps this is an "equivalent" statement to the question)

Comment: @Salcio I am not sure I understand your point. None of the sets in my question needs to be a literal ball in some metric, just homeomorphic to it.

Comment: @MathDrifter I like the idea. I can think of cases that appear tricky to me: think of a 3-ball  $A$ and an open curve inside it whose ends are on the boundary $\partial A$ and that forms a knot inside $A$. A thickening of that curve is a 3-ball $B\subset A$, and collapsing   $A$ onto $B$ seems at least not straightforward.